# How to remove accents from Unicode characters?

Tags: c#, unicode, ascii, diacritics

I have string with Unicode character, example `Hãy đợi đấy`.

I need an (ASCII) output `Hay doi day`.

How can I remove the accents?

Comment: Not an answer but look into Unicode Normalization namely NFD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a library like [UnidecodeSharpFork](https://bitbucket.org/Dimps/unidecodesharpfork) to do that.